# SP Online WCF External Content Types using SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type, wcf

To create External Content Types in SharePoint Online, i have created a WCF service and hosted it in IIS and it is working fine as shown below.
[image: WCF Service]

Now, I tried to create External Content types using SharePoint Designer 2013.
[image: SharePoint Designer configurations]

But, i'm facing this issue.

[image: Issue]

Web.config file
[image: Web config]

Please kindly someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have enable Publish Metadata for the WCF service. You can check the articles about [how to Publish Metadata for a Service using a Configuration File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-a-configuration-file).

[WCF Tutorial - Introduction](http://pages.mini.pw.edu.pl/~porterj/mossakow/materials/presentations/wcf.3.5/introduction/index.html)

If the issue exists, try to add the hostname of address to hosts file and check again.

Comment: Hello,  Thank you for the reply. I have added Web config file in my question i guess i have added all the configurations. Also, in hosts file i have added my system ipaddress and host name still i face same issue.